Boost::Beast websocket client does not send Pong response
I'm developing a websocket clent listening for Binance market data stream to read a quotes. I'm using Boost::Beast websocket for this purpose. The connection uses SSL. My problem is that my client disconnecting because of "pong timeout".
Beast documentation says that websocket should automatically handle control frames and send pong with ongoing read or write operations. Because my websocket stream listening for quotes, it is almost all the time in permanent async_read state - so it either awaits data or reads data. So according to docs it should send pong when ping arrived.
To check whether client receives pings I override control_callback - yes it receives pings. I even tried to send pongs from control callback using async_pong. This method's completion handler repots me that a pong send was successfull, but nothing changes.
To check pong receipt on server side (Binance), I compiled an example of websocket ssl async server from Boost::Beast. I slightly changed it's code so it not echo received requests but rather statrt to send a json with quotes like Binance do. And I override control_callback on server side to see if pongs are coming from my client. They are not.
My question is - why websocket not sending pongs?
Best regards,
Dan

The problem was in a corporate antivirus. It somehow has blocked websocket control frames.
